# react-native-dotenv Unable to resolve module @env

Tags: typescript, react-native, environment-variables, dotenv

I'm setting up this lib for `TypeScript` like [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dotenv)

my `env`:

```
API_KEY=someKey..
```

i'm setting up `type/env.d.ts`:

```
declare module '@env' {
    export const API_KEY: string;
}
```

my `babel.config.ts`:

```
   module.exports = function (api) {
    api.cache(true);
    return {
        presets: ["babel-preset-expo"],
        plugins: [
            [
                "module:react-native-dotenv",
                {
                    moduleName: "@env",
                    path: ".env",
                },
            ],
        ],
    };
};
```

my `config.ts:`

```
import API_KEY from '@env'

export default {API_KEY};
```

`package.json`:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@types/react-native-dotenv": "^0.2.0",
    "expo": "~42.0.1",
    "expo-status-bar": "~1.0.4",
    "foo": "^0.0.7",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-dom": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "https://github.com/expo/react-native/archive/sdk-42.0.0.tar.gz",
    "react-native-config": "^1.4.5",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-web": "~0.13.12",
    "styled-components": "^5.3.0"
  },
```

and this file where i use API_KEY`weather.ts`:

```
Import axios from "axios";
import config from "../../config";

class WeatherService {
  FetchCoordinatesHandler(city) {
    return axios.get(`weather`, {
      params: {
        q: city,
        units: "metric",
        appid: config.API_KEY
      },
    });
  }

  FetchWeatherByCoordinatesHandler({lon, lat}) {

    return axios.get(`onecall`, {
      params: {
        lat: lat,
        lon: lon,
        units: "metric",
        appid: config.API_KEY
      },
    });
  }
}

const weatherServiceInstance = new WeatherService();
export default weatherServiceInstance;
```

and i get this in the console:

```
    Android Bundling failed 8987ms
    Unable to resolve module @env from C:\IT\ReactNative\weather-app\weather-app\config.js: @env could not be found within the project or in these directories:
      node_modules
      ..\node_modules
    > 1 | import API_KEY from '@env'
    |                      ^
  2 |
  3 | export default {API_KEY};
```

[image]

please help :( I don't know what to do, I've looked all over the internet. maybe my dependencies don't have the up-to-date version of something

**`ATTENTION`**
when i change my module from `@env` to `'react-native-dotenv'` i'm still get error but some other:

```
Android Bundling failed 5334ms

    Unable to resolve module fs from C:\IT\ReactNative\weather-app\weather-app\node_modules\react-native-dotenv\index.js: fs could not be found within the project or in t
    hese directories:
      node_modules
      ..\node_modules
    > 1 | const {readFileSync} = require('fs')
        |                                 ^
      2 | const dotenv = require('dotenv')
      3 |
      4 | function parseDotenvFile(path, verbose = false) {
```

[image]

*i hope anyone help me, thanks :)*

Comment: Same problem here, have you found a solution in the mean time?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the fs problem is about that module do not exist in the mobile bundle, i had the same issue and i review a few pages about this project, but i not found answer, maybe this can be helpful, i was re-configurate my environment config,

Dependencies:

```
yarn add dotenv react-native-dotenv expo-constants
```

Create .env file in root project

```
API_URL=https://api.example.org
API_TOKEN=abc123
```

Ignore .env file in .gitignore

Create or update a file app.config.ts in your root project, that export environments vars and the interface for ts typing (like https://docs.expo.dev/guides/environment-variables/)

```
import 'dotenv/config';

export interface AppConfig {
  API_URL: string,
  API_TOKEN: string,
}

export default {
  name: 'CoolApp',
  version: '1.0.0',
  extra: {
    API_URL: process.env.API_URL,
    API_TOKEN: process.env.API_TOKEN,
  },
};
```

Create a config.ts file that export all environment vars to other files

```
    import Constants from 'expo-constants';
    import { AppConfig } from '../../app.config';
    
    const { API_TOKEN, API_URL } = Constants.manifest?.extra as AppConfig;
```

Answer (score 0):

Follow this steps and issue will be resolved.

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules:
   rm -rf node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn
   start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*

Comment: I tried 1 & 3 (reset watchman & metro cache) and ensure I install the package as a ***development dependency***, it works.

thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Oh man, I battled with this problem for so long, but finally got it to work.  These were the steps I took.

1. Sort out the typescript error by running `npx expo install @types/react-native-dotenv -- --dev`  (Note: if you're using npm instead of yarn, use `-- --save-dev` instead of `-- --dev`)
2. Stop the bundler, then restart and **clear the cache** with `npx expo start --clear`
3. Add `"@env": ["node_modules/react-native-dotenv"]` to your compiler options paths in tsconfig.json to help expo find the module:

```
{
  "extends": "expo/tsconfig.base",
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "paths": {
      "src/*": ["src/*"],
      "root/*":["./*"],
      "@env": ["node_modules/react-native-dotenv"]
    }
  },
}
```